# How to trim input audio and then replace it with actual audio of video in single ffmpeg command?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am replacing audio of video in FFmpeg with this command:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -stream_loop -1 -i audio.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy -shortest output.mp4
```

Now what I want to achieve:

above command replace input audio in the video but now I want to use a specific duration of the audio and replace it in the video.

**E.X** input audio duration is 00:05:00(5 min) and I want to trim 00:02:00(start time) to 00:03:00(end time ) means 1 min audio and replace it in the video. I don't want to use full input audio.

all in single FFmpeg command(which I provided above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `-t`/`-to` with `-stream_loop`. <strike>Lazy</strike> Easy solution is to trim the audio then run your command:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:02:00 -t 00:01:00 -i audio.mp3 -c copy audio-trimmed.mp3
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -stream_loop -1 -i audio-trimmed.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy -shortest output.mp4
```

Single command using [aloop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aloop) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -ss 00:02:00 -t 00:01:00 -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex "[1]aloop=loop=-1:size=<size>,asetpts=N/SR/TB[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -shortest output.mp4
```

You'll have to manually enter `<size>` value which is max number of samples to loop. Default value is 0.

Comment: can i do this in single command?

Comment: and also can you please help me with this question https://superuser.com/questions/1546427/how-to-adjust-volume-of-input-video-and-input-audio-while-adding-input-audio-to

Comment: @MilanTejani I did not see a requirement that it needed to be a single command in your question. Why do you want it to be a single command?

Comment: I am just curious and I have another doubt what if i want to keep both audio 1. input audio and 2. original audio of video

Comment: in the above command, it replaces the original audio of video with the input audio

Comment: @MilanTejani *"it replaces the original audio of video with the input audio"* That's what you asked for in the original question. If you want to mix them you need to ask a new question because it's completely different. I may provide the single command version tomorrow, but there are so many questions to answer.

Comment: i already asked question check this https://superuser.com/questions/1546427/how-to-adjust-volume-of-input-video-and-input-audio-while-adding-input-audio-to

Comment: can you provide sources to learn FFmpeg in deep like any books, online tutorial websites or udemy or other learning app's course?

Comment: @MilanTejani See [Can anyone recommend any good guides to ffmpeg outside of the official manual?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/25467/can-anyone-recommend-any-good-guides-to-ffmpeg-outside-of-the-official-manual)

Comment: @MilanTejani Updated answer with single command version.

Comment: my video duration is 03:05 and i get only 01:02 in output because i take 1 min of audio from mp3 file.i didn't get full video with loop audio

Comment: can I control the volume of both audio and video? I want to set audio volume 0.3 and video volume 0.7 can i do this in above command